# How to say "oath-breaker" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

How can I translate "oath-breaker" properly into Latin in reference to losing one's faith?

Comment: Welcome to the site! By faith you mean trust in someone else, or in God? Who is the oath-breaker, the one trusting or the one being trusted?

Comment: And what does losing one's faith have to do with breaking an oath? I'm not seeing the connection here. Can you elaborate a bit more on what you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

An oath-breaker is ***periurus***, but note that this word can also refer to a perjurer (one who lies under oath), or a liar, an untruthful person in general.

Although Cicero thought that lying under oath was not *periurare* ([Off. 3, 108](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/off3.shtml#108)):

> Non enim falsum iurare periurare est, sed quod ex animi tui sententia iuraris, sicut verbis concipitur more nostro, id non facere periurium est.

⋯ which would be oath-breaking in the strict sense.

A less ambiguous form would be *qui, quod iuravit, non facit*, or: *qui iusiurandum violat*.

None of this has anything to do with “losing one's faith,” though.